# Avoid duplication of null type checking in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, static-typing

My current goal is to remove this code duplication:

```dart
final int? myNullableInt = 10;

/// Everywhere I need to do this null verification:
if (myNullableInt == null) return null;

return someOtherMethodThatReceivesANonNullableInt(myNullableInt);
```

I want to convert to something like we have in Kotlin:

```dart
final int? myNullableInt = 10;

return myNullableInt?.apply((myInt) => someOtherMethodThatReceivesANonNullableInt(myInt));
```

I did it:

```dart
extension ApplyIfNotNull on Object? {
  T? apply<T extends Object?>(Object? obj, T? Function(Object) fn) {
    if (obj == null) return null;
    return fn(obj);
  }
}
```

But this gives me a static error:

```dart
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
```

Note: this should work with all types, e.g `int`s, `String`s, `double` and `MyOwnClassType`s.

Is there something I can do? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```dart
> extension ApplyIfNotNull on Object? {
>   T? apply<T extends Object?>(Object? obj, T? Function(Object) fn) {
>     if (obj == null) return null;
>     return fn(obj);
>   }
> }
> ```

That doesn't work because it declares that the callback be capable of accepting any `Object` argument, but you're presumably trying to use it with a function that accepts only an `int` argument.  It's also unclear why you've made an extension method since it doesn't involve the receiver (`this`) at all.

You need to make your function generic on the callback's argument type as well:

```dart
R? applyIfNotNull<R, T>(T? obj, R Function(T) f) =>
    (obj == null) ? null : f(obj);
```

(That's the same as what I suggested in https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360#issuecomment-502423488 but with the arguments reversed.)

Or, as an extension method, so that it can work on `this` instead of having the extra `obj` argument:

```dart
extension ApplyIfNotNull<T> on T? {
  R? apply<R>(R Function(T) f) {
    // Local variable to allow automatic type promotion.  Also see:
    // <https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1397>
    final self = this;
    return (self == null) ? null : f(self);
  }
}
```

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360 for the existing language feature request and for some other suggested workarounds in the meantime.